# Execute Multiple Send-Requests in a single Call

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an Azure APIM service where a user makes a call to request data via one service.  Unfortunately, in the source API, to retrieve all the required information, I need to iterate over the initial result set and make a number of successive calls whereby I can then inject the results of those calls into the initial results.

I have done the work to parse our and create the new json results in C# but can't find a way to trigger multiple requests to go get more data?

Also, I am doing this in the Outbound node of the policy so the code looks something like this...

```
<INBOUND>
   <SEND-REQUEST>
</INBOUND>
<OUTBOUND>
   <RETURN-RESPONSE>
      <SET-BODY>@{

          //Some C# code here where I go over the results of the initial SEND-REQUEST and then make successive calls before returning to the client

      }</SET-BODY>
   </RETURN-RESPONSE>
</OUTBOUND>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this in the Outbound node of the policy

Azure API Management (APIM) policies execute one after the other. there is no built-in support for parallel execution of multiple `<send-request>` policies within a single policy execution.

- [Send request policy](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/send-request-policy.md) I had referred this doc and there is a note that the policy itself does not inherently support parallel execution of multiple requests within a single policy execution.

Still, if you want to execute multiple requests use Azure Functions, Logic Apps, or even handling parallelism on the client side but not in APIM.

- Create a function app with HttpTrigger and follow the below code.

```cs
public static class ParallelAggregationFunction
{
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    [FunctionName("ParallelAggregation")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Make parallel requests
            var request1Task = FetchDataAsync("https://api.example.com/data1");
            var request2Task = FetchDataAsync("https://api.example.com/data2");

            // Wait for both requests to complete
            await Task.WhenAll(request1Task, request2Task);

            // Get the results
            var data1 = await request1Task;
            var data2 = await request2Task;

            // Aggregate the data
            var aggregatedData = new
            {
                Data1 = data1,
                Data2 = data2
            };

            // Serialize the aggregated data to JSON
            var responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aggregatedData);

            // Return the JSON response
            return new OkObjectResult(responseJson);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, "An error occurred");
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> FetchDataAsync(string apiUrl)
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

- Create two parallel request tasks to fetch data from different API endpoints. `Task.WhenAll` is used to complete both tasks in parallel. aggregate the data into a single object and serialize the aggregated data to JSON.
- Deploy the above application to function app and navigate to create new API select existing one and integrate

**`<send-request>` policy:**

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="WebApp_mydjsampleapp1" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <!-- Make the request to the Azure Function -->
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="functionResponse">
            <set-url>https://donglefunc1.azurewebsites.net</set-url>
            <set-method>GET</set-method>
        </send-request>
        
        <!-- Process the response from the Azure Function -->
        <set-body>@{
            // Extract the response from the functionResponse variable
            string responseBody = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("functionResponse");
            
            // Process the responseBody as needed (e.g., transform or aggregate)
            // Then, return the modified response body
            return responseBody;
        }</set-body>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

- In the example above, I've shown a placeholder where you can perform any necessary transformations or aggregations on the response data.